# What are the best steps to install ZeroMQ in Windows 10 64 bit?

Tags: php, zeromq

I am trying to install ZeroMQ in my windows.

I have xampp and **`php`** version 7.0, so what are the best steps to install this library?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Try this](http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows)

You can directly download and install .exe file

Comment: i am tried to do this, but i have some problems, please help me to find best installer and the other steps after installing it.

Comment: i installed the library from this link http://miru.hk/archive/ZeroMQ-4.0.4~miru1.0-x64.exe

Comment: Whats the problem ?

Comment: i installed the library and downloaded the dll files from php pecl site, and put them inside xampp/php and xampp/php/ext folders, then when restart xampp i have this problem ..PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: https://github.com/kirensiva/zmqPHPVersion5.6.3/archive/master.zip try this dll file

Comment: download dll from http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.2/windows

Copy the `php_zmq.dll` to `php/ext` directory

Then copy the `libzmq.dll` to the `xamp/` root directory

RESTART apache.

Comment: i think their is a step between installing zmq and putting files in php folder, but i miss it

Comment: no i think the last comment from you will not work because i explained that have 7.0 php version

Comment: download zmq from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/

Comment: First download zmq from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/
according to your pc 32 bit or 64 bit choose 1.1.3-70 version
Then download dll thread safe 
Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Make sure you download the correct .DLL for your php installation, Also if you're running PHP as an Apache module, make sure you pick the thread safe, if you're running apache x86 download an x86 php_mongo.dll, pick  type of dll that matches the php version you're running,versions must match or else you will get a php startup error

Comment: Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### Have you tried [official ZeroMQ recipe](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php)?

> **Windows**
>   Download the latest snapshot from **http://snapshot.zero.mq/**
>   Copy `libzmq.dll` into your php directory (e.g. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8)
>   Copy the appropriate version of `php_zmq.dll` to your php extension directory (e.g. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext)
>   Add the following line to your **`php.ini`**:
>       `extension=php_zmq.dll`
>   Restart your web server to pickup the ini changes

---

### Another way to have ZeroMQ / php up and running w/o installing:

Next, you may opt to use a pre-installed VM-image, with ZeroMQ already setup and RTO.